# Is there any way we can hide bars based on their values like negative / positive?

Tags: javascript, charts, bar-chart, lightningchart

I am using LightningChartJS to create chart with bars. I have data with both positive and negative values. Is there any available property using which I can hide negative bars or positive bars based on what i want to see?

Note: I can obviously write some basic logic to achieve this functionality but i am looking for some inbuilt functionality.

```
const rectangles = chart.addRectangleSeries()
const addValues = (entries) => {
      for (const entry of entries) {
        bars.push(add(entry))
      }
}


const add = (entry) => {
      // Create rect dimentions.
      const rectDimensions = {
        x: x - figureThickness,
        y: 0,
        width: figureThickness,
        height: entry.value
      }
      // Add rect to the series.
      x += figureThickness + figureGap
      // Return data-structure with both original 'entry' and the rectangle figure that represents it.
      return {
        entry,
        rect
      }
    }

    chart.addValues([
  { category: '', value: 20 },
  { category: '', value: 40 },
  { category: '', value: -23 },
  { category: '', value: -29 },
  { category: '', value: 15 }
])
```

Comment: Can you please add some code of what you're having currently working so that it's easier to suggest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To hide series/figures based on value, you do have to implement this logic on the application side.

For this you have two options:

1. Separate the bars to two RectangleSeries, one which has positive values and the another with negative ones.
2. Use just one RectangleSeries like you have now, but style each figure individually. You receive a reference to the figure when you add a rectangle with RectangleSeries.add().

In either case, you'll have to dispose to hide series/figures you **dont** want to see, and restore the things you want to see. Both RectangleSeries and figures have the dispose() and restore() methods.

Comment: I had something similar in my mind. I was looking for some in built API which could do the same work for me. Anyway the workaround seems to do the job. thanks